# Django Rest Framework custom api.html throws warnings on OPTIONS request ajax form

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, ajax

I'm building my custom `api.html` template for Django Rest Framework api project (based on the official `base.html` template to customize mine), but I'm facing some issues implementing the **OPTIONS** button. Here it is my code:

```html
{% load static %} {% load i18n %} {% load rest_framework %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" id="myHtml">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>My project title</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'assets/compass-fill.ico' %}" />

    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      id="theme-link"
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://bootswatch.com/5/darkly/bootstrap.min.css"
      type="text/css"
    />

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css"
    />

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/4.3.0/jquery.form.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      ...
      {% if options_form %}
      <form
        class="button-form"
        action="{{ request.get_full_path }}"
        data-method="OPTIONS"
      >
        <button
          type="submit"
          class="btn btn-primary"
          data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
          data-bs-title="Make an OPTIONS request on the {{ name }} resource"
          data-bs-custom-class="tooltip-success"
        >
          OPTIONS
        </button>
      </form>
      {% endif %}
      ...
    </div>
    ...
    <script type="application/json" id="drf_csrf">
      {
        "csrfHeaderName": "{{ csrf_header_name|default:'X-CSRFToken' }}",
        "csrfToken": "{% if request %}{{ csrf_token }}{% endif %}"
      }
    </script>
    <script src="{% static 'rest_framework/js/ajax-form.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'rest_framework/js/load-ajax-form.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'rest_framework/js/csrf.js' %}"></script>
    <script> 
      const themeLink = document.getElementById("theme-link");
      ...my other scripts...
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I created the OPTIONS button like in the original template [base.html](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/templates/rest_framework/base.html) and in the end of the body I loaded js functions without them the button function not works properly.
In fact, if clicked it shows the drf option content but unfortunately it will throw warnings and errors, like if it replace entire html page but keeping old elements and after click shows inside the console:

```
...
A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js, is invoked via document.write. 
The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. 
If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message. 
See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.
...
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'themeLink' has already been declared (at (index):1:13761)
```

Seems like the ajax call is causing all this troubles, but I just created functions, copied from the official repo branch files ([load-ajax-form.js](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/static/rest_framework/js/load-ajax-form.js), [ajax-form.js](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/static/rest_framework/js/ajax-form.js), [csrf.js](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/static/rest_framework/js/csrf.js)) and put them inside my `static/rest_framework/js` folder.

Where I'm wrong on customize the template ?